# Use the same class as Input and Object type in GraphQL in NestJS

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs

I am trying to setup my graphql resover to handle an array of objects but cant get the @Args  decorator configured.

I created my own ArgsType

```
import { ArgsType, Field, Int, ObjectType } from '@nestjs/graphql';

@ArgsType()  // to be used as type in the resolver
@ObjectType()  // for schema generation 
export class Club {
 @Field(type => String)
 president: string;

 @Field(type => Int)
 members?: number;
}
```

Resolver with adding a single Club works just fine!

```
 @Query(() => Int)
 async addClub(@Args() club: Club) {
  // handle stuff
  }
```

but if I want to give an array of Club like this

```
 @Query(() => Int)
   async addClubs(@Args({name: 'clubs', type: () => [Club]}) clubs: Array<Club>) {
   // handle stuff
  }
```

this thows an error when nest is starting up

```
 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot determine a GraphQL input type for the "clubs". Make sure your class is decorated with an appropriate decorator.
```

although I am able to use an  array of Strings like this

```
 @Query(() => [String])
 async addStrings(@Args({ name: 'clubs', type: () => [String], }) clubs: Array<string>) {
  // handle stuff
  }
```

I am pretty sure there should be an easy solution, but cant figure out where to go from here.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to the error,

```sh
Cannot determine a GraphQL input type for the "clubs". Make sure your class is decorated with an appropriate decorator
```

You're trying to use `Club` class as a GraphQL input type while it is already an object type (According to `@ObjectType` annotation you use).

---

**Solution 1:**

I would suggest you write a separate GraphQL input type like below (not tested). This is cleaner and less coupled if you need to separate the way you treat input and output of `Club`.

```js
import { InputType, Field } from '@nestjs/graphql';

@InputType()
export class ClubInput {
 @Field()
 president: string;

 @Field()
 members?: number;
}
```

Then in your resolver, you can use it like below.

```js
@Query(() => Int)
async addClubs(@Args({name: 'clubs', type: () => [ClubInput]}) clubs: Array<ClubInput>) {
 // handle stuff
}
```

---

**Solution 2:**

But if you really need to use the same class for both purposes, you could try to create both input and object types with the same `Club` name. The name of the object type is by default the name of the class. So you need to provide the name explicitly to avoid conflict.

```js
import { Field, Int, ObjectType, InputType } from '@nestjs/graphql';

@InputType("ClubInput")
@ObjectType("ClubType")
export class Club {
 @Field(type => String)
 president: string;

 @Field(type => Int)
 members?: number;
}
```

Now your `Club` has different names for input and object types. Then in your resolver, you can use it like below.

```js
@Query(() => Int)
async addClubs(@Args({name: 'clubs', type: () => [ClubInput]}) clubs: Array<ClubInput>) {
 // handle stuff
}
```

**Note:** In this solution, you need to make sure that `Club` will never contain fields that express circular references or references to interfaces and unions. If that is going to happen, you will have to move to Solution 1, else this will make your input throw an error.

---

The take away is that in Typescript GraphQL, `InputType` and `ObjectType` are two different concepts and we need to use it properly to avoid any issues.

Comment: Wow thanks for that thorough explanation. So it was basically me trying to use a screwdriver as a hammer xD had no time to try it out but after checking the nestjs docs about graphql mutation, I am sure that's the solution. I will stick with solution 1 since that's the common practice and my case is not special at all

Comment: Please do you know how someone can go about this case. I have an `InputType` and `ObjectType`, most of their properties are same but they have few differences, is there a way i can have 2 classes where one inherits the similar properties from the other so i won't have to define duplicate properties in both classes

Comment: Sure, You can create an abstract class and put the similar properties of `InputType` and `ObjectType` in it. Then you can extend that class in your `InputType` and `ObjectType` concrete classes.

Comment: https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/mapped-types this gives you a nice abstraction to achieve what you wish