# nestjs graphql with entity relations - how to decorate it?

Tags: graphql, nestjs

I have a problem "decorating" classes which should be used as ObejctType AND as InputType when I have relations. It should be possible to use the relation class also in other classes

e.g. Customer with Address, User with Address

```
@ObjectType()
@InputType()
export class Address {
  @Field()
  street: string;

  @Field()
  city: string;
}


@ObjectType()
@InputType()
export class Customer {
  @Field()
  name: string;

  @Field(() => Address)
  address: Address;
}


@ObjectType()
@InputType()
export class User {
  @Field()
  name: string;

  @Field(() => Address)
  address: Address;
}
```

I would like to use Customer and User also as input parameter for Mutations. But I have no success. I tried variations with "isAbstract" option for InputType and ObjectType but I am not pleased with this solution.

Can anybody of you give me a hint how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you getting a conflict error, you need to explicitly specify the name of ObjectTypes and InputTypes.

So try something like this:

```
@ObjectType("AddressType")
@InputType("AddressInput")
export class Address {
  @Field()
  street: string;

  @Field()
  city: string;
}
```

See this [Use the same class as Input and Object type in GraphQL in NestJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64607530/5289334).

Comment: Thank you for answering. Yeah "naming" of InputType and ObjectType works.